# Error al hacer un GET con Proxies

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

El proyecto que estoy haciendo ahora es un **comprobador de proxies**. Básicamente que compruebe si realmente cambia la IP haciendo una **petición con el modulo requests**.

El programa funciona bien sin proxies, devolviendo obviamente mi IP, sin embargo si pongo los proxies no va.

El archivo del que se importan los proxies tiene un proxy por línea, en formato:

> IP:PUERTO

Este es el código:

```
from colorama import Fore
import requests
import json
import os


def check():
    count = 0
    os.system("cls")
    fichero = open("proxygen.txt","r+")
    for ip_port in fichero:
        todo = ip_port.split(":")
        ip = todo[0]
        port = todo[1]
        line = 'http://' + ip + ':' + port
        proxies = {'http': line,'https': line}
        try:
            testIP = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip',proxies=proxies,timeout = 3)
            resIP = testIP.json()["origin"]
            origin = resIP.split(",")
            if origin[0] == ip:
                print(f"Proxy {origin}        OK")
                proxyList.append(line)
            else:
                print (f"Bad Proxy {origin} ")



        except:
            print (f"proxy {origin[0]} error")

check()
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes en principio dos errores:

- Tanto cuando iteras sobre las lineas de un fichero con un `for-in`, usas `readlines` o generas otro iterables a partir de las lineas del fichero (p.e: `list(file)`) se usa internamente `readline` y `readline` **no elimina nunca el carácter o caracteres de nueva linea**. Esto causa que quede al final del puerto, generando ips de la forma:

  > 'http:/130.61.35.198:4554\n'

  lo cual es una ip inválida. Debes eliminar dichos caracteres explícitamente , lo puedes hacer con `str.split()` o `str.rsplit()`
- Usas la variable `origin` en el bloque del `except`, pero esta variable **no estará definida si el bloque del `try` ocasiona una excepción antes  de la línea `origin = resIP.split(",")`**, lo que es de esperar.

Podría quedar algo así:

```
import requests
import json
import os


def check(file):
    proxy_list = []
    os.system("cls")
    with open(file) as fichero:
        for ip_port in fichero:
            ip, port = ip_port.rstrip().split(":")
            line = f'http://{ip}:{port}'
            proxies = {'http': line, 'https': line}
            try:
                testIP = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxies, timeout=3)
                resIP = testIP.json()["origin"]
                origin = resIP.split(",")[0]
            else:
                if origin == ip:
                    print(f"Proxy {ip:17}    OK")
                    proxy_list.append(ip)
                else:
                    print(f"Proxy {ip:17}   BAD")
            except:
                print(f"Proxy {ip:17} ERROR")
    return proxy_list

proxy_list = check("proxygen.txt")
```

Ten en cuenta que es siempre buena idea y buena práctica incluir en el `try` exclusivamente aquello cuyos posibles errores queramos capturar.

Por otro lado, es también buena práctica cerrar cualquier archivo abierto de forma explícita, bien usando el método `close` o bien usando el administrador de contexto con `with`. El recolector de basura terminará haciéndolo una vez la función retorne, pero no se debe dejar esto a al GC.